# Find duplicate webaddress through regex

Tags: regex, duplicates, webaddress

If someone types webadress twice by wrongly i want to find the duplicate webaddress using regex. Example:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?
```

It should throw an error.

I check the rule `\b(\w+)\s+\1\b`, it's not working for me.

Can someone help me to find the rule?

Comment: Why the `\s+`, there are no spaces in there? And `\w` won't match all characters in a typical URL. And the last `\b` makes it not work in this case 'cause there's no `\b` after a `?`.

Comment: `/(.*)\1/` works, does it have to be more exact than that?

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because `(\w+)` is just for characters.

Looks like you want to search for non-whitespace characters in a string that starts with "http://"

You could do that like this: `\b(http://\S+)\s*\1`

Comment: It works with the example *if* you remove the last `\b` (see my comment to the question) (and escape the slashes, but that could depend on the engine).

Comment: @Biffen Thanks, I reflexively added back the `\b` but I'm still surprised it did not work. Is there a reason that trailing `\b`s are not allowed?

Comment: In this case it's because there's no `\b` after a `?`; `\b` is for *word* boundaries, and `?` is not a word character.